# How to calculate third point if I know 2 points and all angles into triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

How to get coordinates of (x,y) of C?
[image]

Comment: Here $|AB|=|AC|$

Answer (score 1):

Solve this equations: $${ \left( 10-3 \right)  }^{ 2 }+{ \left( 10-4 \right)  }^{ 2 }=|AB|\\ { \left( x-3 \right)  }^{ 2 }+{ \left( y-4 \right)  }^{ 2 }=|AC|\\ { \left( x-10 \right)  }^{ 2 }+{ \left( y-10 \right)  }^{ 2 }=|BC|=|AC|\\ \\ \frac { |AB| }{ \sin { (100) }  } =\frac { |BC| }{ \sin { (40) }  } $$
where $(x,y)$ is the coordinates of $C$.